# Xamarin - adding swipe to a UIVIEW

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new using Xamarin and I'm trying to learn it by converting an App I built using Titanium in the past. Actually I'm stucked trying to add swipe on my UIView. I checked the documentation and also I found a similar code here in Stack Overflow, but it's not working anyway. Can someone point me what's wrong ? ty !

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipe;
    ...
}

private void addSwipe()
{
    nfloat vpHeight = View.Bounds.Height;
    nfloat vpWidth = View.Bounds.Width;
    var mainContainer = new UIView()
    {
        Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight),
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
    };
    swipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer();
    mainContainer.AddGestureRecognizer(swipe);
    if (swipe.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a handler when you create your recognizer:

```
   swipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer( (s) =>
   {
       if (s.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up)
       {
          Console.WriteLine("up");
       }
   });
```

Comment: Sorry...no effect. I set my code to : swipe = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((s) =>
   {
      if (s.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up)
      {
       Console.WriteLine("up");
      }
   });
   mainContainer.AddGestureRecognizer(swipe);

Comment: you are attaching the gesture to mainContainer - but do you ever add that view to the view hierarchy?

Comment: yep ! this.View.Add(mainContainer);

Comment: weird. You might try adding a Tap gesture instead, just to see if that works.  I did something very similar to this yesterday and the basic approach should work fine.

Comment: I appreciate anyway, Jason ! It could be a good hint to go forward :) cheers !

Comment: Hey..it's weird...it's works, but only if the direction is...right ??!! Console.WriteLine(s);  ---->  <UISwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x7ff31c459790; state = Ended; view = <UIView 0x7ff31c4593b0>; target= <(action=target:, target=<__UISwipeGestureRecognizer 0x600001227900>)>; direction = right>

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on my own...

```
public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
{
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipe;
  ...
}

private void addSwipe()
{
    nfloat vpHeight = View.Bounds.Height;
    nfloat vpWidth = View.Bounds.Width;
    var mainContainer = new UIView()
    {
      Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, vpWidth, vpHeight),
      BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red
    };
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeUp = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(OnSwipeUp);
    swipeUp.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up;
    mainContainer.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeUp);
}
private void OnSwipeUp() {
  Console.Writeline("Up");
}
```